# Does Dart have fixed size arrays?

Tags: dart

I'm writing a program that uses MidiNotes. Each song can be programmed to be played depending ona  bit 0 or 1 in a fixed sized array of 128 bits.

On Dart it seems like it's only possible to create functions that expect dynamically sized lists:

```
void something(List<bool> midiNotes)
```

this way the user can forget to set the 128 bits and just pass an empty list or a list with just one element.

Comment: There are fixed size lists in Dart but you cannot require a given length as a type in Dart. If it is important to set a specific amount of bits, I will suggest you to create your own type which represent 128 bits of nodes. Then the user of your lib needs to call your constructor to create this object which can then require the user to specify the bits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will put these two links as a reference

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.3/dart-core/List/List.html
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/List/List.filled.html

In your case, I would reccomend

```
const List<bool> myList = [/*...*/];
// just use const
```

However, if this doesn't work, you can use this.

the List constructor is like this

```dart
List<E>([int? length])
```

If you say something like

```dart
List<bool> fixedLengthList = List<bool>(10)
```

Then anything which will change the `List`'s length will throw an error.

If you want something like

```dart
List<bool> fixedLengthList = [true, true, true];
```

then use

```dart
List<bool> fixedLengthList = List<bool>.filled(3, true);
/// you can add growable: false if you want but it is useless
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<data_type> tempData =
      List.filled(initial_size, initial_val, growable: false);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?